# Regular Expression cleaning except abbreviations

Tags: python, regex

I'm using `[^A-Za-z']` expression to clean data from a CSV file before processing it. But I want to keep dots for abbreviations (such as U.S)
I want to exclude `[A-Za-z]\.[A-Za-z]` from `[^A-Za-z']`. How can I do that?

Edit:
To make it clearer. I will provide an example sentence:

> "The plastic buildout in the U.S. is clustered in the Gulf of Mexico
>   region, where much of the U.S. petrochemical industry is already
>   located."

I convert to lowercase, clean any characters that aren't alphabetical and divide the sentence into words. When I'm cleaning it, I get the result:

> "the plastic buildout in the u s is clustered in the gulf of mexico
>   region where much of the u s petrochemical industry is already
>   located"

I want to exclude `[A-Za-z]\.[A-Za-z]` to ignore U.S

The line of code:

```
corpus_text['Sentence'] = corpus_text['Sentence'].str.replace("[^A-Za-z']", ' ').str.lower()
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you want.  Can you provide examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I reading your question correctly, that you want to remove all non A-Za-z characters, except if there is a dot in the middle, e.g.

- U.S  -->  U.S
- U.S. -->  U.S
- end of sentence. --> end of sentence
- an ellipsis ... like this --> an ellipsis like this

That means that any trailing dots, like at the end of a sentence still need to be removed.
So, clean out any optional trailing dots, followed by non alpha or non-dot characters:

```
\.*[^A-Za-z\.]
```